# Strange behavior when placing a Legend on a GraphicsRow, Column or Grid

Tags: graphics, legending, grid-layouts, version-12.0

Consider the following example:

```
p = Plot[x^2, {x,0,1}]
r1 = Legended[GraphicsRow[{p,p}], Placed["x", {{0,0.5}, {0,0.5}}]]
r2 = Legended[GraphicsRow[{p,p}], Placed["x", {{1,0.5}, {1,0.5}}]]
```

As I understand it, this should place the legend against the left and right edges of the graphic respectively, and that is indeed what happens when using a single plot. But when applying the legend to a row, I get the following:

```
Show[r1]
```

[image]

```
Show[r2]
```

[image]

As you can see, the legend is (correctly) vertically centered, but the horizontal placement is messed up: the scaled positions 0 and 1 are not the edges of the row, but something in between. (The plots are also being clipped for some reason.) Why does this happen?

Comment: What version and OS are you using? With `12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)` the legends are on the left and right edges.

Comment: @BobHanlon I'm on 12.0.0.0 for Windows 64-bit. That's interesting...

Comment: I can reproduce your results on `12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)` but works properly on `12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)`